# Same code while running on different Visual Studio version gives different output(Code and framework remains unchanged)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I have developed an application which creates a file in the location where the exe is located(In our case "*C:\Program Files....\MyApplication*")

**Same code while running on different Visual Studio version gives different output:**

The Scenerio is as below:

**Environment 1:** VisualStudio2005, .Net Framework 2.0

**Output:** The file is automatically created in the Users folder(*C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\VirtualStore*), not in the location of the exe(*C:\Program Files....\MyApplication*)

**Environment 2:** VisualStudio2008, .Net Framework 2.0

**Output:** The application doesnot run and shows File access error("Access to the path "*C:\Program Files.....\MyApplication\File.txt*" is denied).

Could you please help to analyse the change in behaviour when Visual Studio version is changed to 2008 from 2005(Code and framework remains unchanged)?

Thank You.

Comment: Check the .Net *runtime* version that executes the code. I assume you are running the app from within the IDE? (i.e. "Run (debug)" or "Run (release)" button?)

Comment: Please add the code that determines where the file is saved to your question

Comment: Are both VS versions on the same machine, or on different versions of Windows?

Comment: .Net 2... whoa that's soo 2006

Comment: @MichaelRandall Well, some companies do have something called "legacy code" ... and that's fair enough. If it ain't broke, don't fix it. And 2006 is really nothing in comparison with what I am dealing here at my place right now ... :(

Comment: But, Show me the code.

Comment: VS2005 was released before Vista, the Windows version that added UAC.  The program it builds, assuming VS was not properly updated, does not have a manifest that declares it compatible with UAC.  So you get the appcompat behavior with files getting moved into the VirtualStore directory, emulating the behavior of the bad old days when just about every user had an admin account.  VS2008 is definitely UAC aware, you'd have to add a manifest and remove the UAC declaration to get the bad old days behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, if it's on the same machine, is probably not your code, nor that you're running versions of Visual Studio and .Net that are wholly unsupported by modern operating systems. C:\Program Files and c:\Program Files(x86) are protected by Windows permissions and User Account Control.  If VS isn't running as an administrator or your account is local admin, you will likely be prohibited from building straight into this directory. Right click on the VS 2008 executable and make sure it's been set to run as Administrator in its properties.

Comment: Yes, it works as an administrator. But I am unsure why two different behaviour while running the application as a normal user.
i.e if the path is inaccessible why in 2005 it automatically takes the User account and saves the file there , but in 2008 it shows error message.

Comment: It's possible that VS 2005 was installed as administrator, and VS 2008 was not.  
VS 2005 may also be emulating "Virtualized" deployment, where as VS 2008 is attempting true deployment to the folder.
Either way, this is actually desirable; I don't recommend ever deploying directly to the UAC protected folders.